# Security problem while trying to load image from server disk in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, actionscript, localhost

I encountered error **#2148**(which is security) when i was trying to load an image file.

1.If i load the swf file in **local**, the image s retrieved and displayed properly.

2.But if i publish the swf file into my web project and run it in **localhost**, it gives me #2148 security error

3.If I use http://xx.xx/ticketstub.png in loadImage() function, it works in both **1** and **2**;
The problem now is when i use C:/jbdevstudio/uploads/ticketdesign/ticketstub.png it isnt working in web server.

Any idea how can i solve this or Flash simply doesnt support this. I had googled this issue for few days and try out any solutions i found but no luck still.

Thanks!

ActionScript codes:

```
//http://xx.xx/ticketstub.png works in both 1 and 2
loadImage("C:/jbdevstudio/uploads/ticketdesign/ticketstub.png");


function loadImage(url:String):void {
try{
 // Set properties on my Loader object
 imageLoader = new Loader();
 imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
 imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, imageLoading);
 imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
}catch(error:Error){
    ExternalInterface.call("er", error.toString()); 
}
}


function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
try{
 // Load Image
 imageHolder.addChild(imageLoader);
 imageHolder.width = imageHolder.width / 3.5;
 imageHolder.height = imageHolder.height / 3.5;
}catch(error:Error){        
    ExternalInterface.call("er", error.toString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load an image from your local file system in Flash like this.

Images can be loaded from a web URL. If they come from a different domain to the SWF, you can only display them, not process them. However, with additional security support (proxy or crossdomain.xml) you can load images from another domain, and process them as you need.

The third option is to upload an image provided by the user through the `FileReference` class, however, the user selects the file, the SWF cannot select it directly. These files can be processed in any way you like.

Comment: This is mostly correct, except that you can load images and video cross-domain.  You just can't read the loaded bytes without a crossdomain.xml policy file.

Comment: Yes, good catch... you can display the image / video as is, but cannot process it beyond that. I've updated my answer to fix that error.

Comment: @James, I forget, can you apply filters to an image without crossdomain?

Comment: Hi, does that mean the "c:\path\image.png" cannot be used ?  and "http://xx.xx/image.png" is the only way? Because my image files are always in the same machine that the server is running in. I am quite confused :D  Thanks again!

Comment: @Wilson60, Flex apps that run inside the browser work like every other browser app.  They can't access local resources.  If you need to access local resources then create an AIR app (with Flex).

Comment: @slomojo, I believe that regular Flash Player filters can be applied but nothing that would read the bitmap's data would work (ie. a PixelBender Filter).

Comment: @Wilson60 I hope this is cleared up... you cannot access files on the server using a windows drive path... it's not possible in HTML so it's not possible in Flash/Flex... because the SWF instance actually running on the server is only able to see what the server allows it to see over http. Knowledge of this is generally taken for granted, but I can understand the confusion, read more about HTTP servers to help get your head around it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) I ll solved it with both your advises.